# How to insert initial data( master data) into SQLite in React Native?

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

I challenge to insert master data into SQLite in React Native.
But The data was inserted into SQLite table every time when I start my application.

Comment: what exactly do you want to ask? Your question isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

Modules allow access to the **database** and **transactions** for data to be placed in the **database** repository.

and You can use **AsyncStorage**

**Example**

```js
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import { openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
let db = openDatabase({ name: 'openDatabase.db' });
...
  register_user = async () => {
    const { user_name } = this.state;
    const { user_address } = this.state;
    if (user_name) {
        if (user_address) {
          db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(
              'INSERT INTO table_user (user_name, user_address) VALUES (?,?,?)',
              [user_name, user_address],
              (tx, results) => {
                console.log('Results', results.rowsAffected);
                if (results.rowsAffected > 0) {
                  await AsyncStorage.setItem('First',true);
                  Alert.alert(
                    'Success',
                    'You are Registered Successfully'
                  );
                } else {
                  alert('Registration Failed');
                }
              }
            );
          });
        } else {
          alert('Please fill Address');
        }
    } else {
      alert('Please fill Name');
    }
  };

async componentDidmount(){
 const check = await AsyncStorage.getItem('First');
  if(check !== true) {
    this.register_user();
  }
}
```

Comment: i have some issues with the sqlite in react native, can you help me please ?

Comment: i have same issue too, any one here for help ?